# retrieve facebook photo albums

Tags: facebook

is there a way or a script to download all the photos from a facebook album, i have more than 3000 photos to download i cant go one by one...
thanks in advance

Comment: If facebook doesn't provide an API for this, it would be difficult to do so.

Comment: ive found this addon for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-photo-album-downloade/ but it doesnt work neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the Graph API documentation for [albums](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) and [photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). There is no API for doing what you're asking (and I would say it's usually discouraged) but you could write a script that uses the above two methods to access each source image.

Comment: I second this, it's probably the fastest way to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

i have a little project i made in the subject, resembling elcpicker.

here's the link: http://www.paladev.com/Archive.zip

in order to open that controller, do something like that:
    -(IBAction)launchFBPicker {

```
FBAlbumChooser *c = [[FBAlbumChooser alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBAlbumChooser" bundle:nil];     
FBPickerController* navController = [[FBPickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

}

hope that helps

good luck!